# pymongo how to query nested document to ignore the key but get its value?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a documents inserted in mongoDB in the format as below:

```
{'Name':{'Surname':{'JON':{'AGE':10}}}}
```

In the example above I want to build a query to ignor the 'JON' but fetch AGE value of all users.

I tried like:

```
db.names.find({'Name.Surname':{$regex:'.'}}) but didn't work....
```

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
db.names.find({'Name.Surname.<matchanything>.AGE':{$gt:0}})
```

Comment: The JSON document you provided is not valid. Do you mean `{'Surname': "JON", 'AGE': 10}`?

Comment: Sorry Corrected it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: There is also some [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/r4laV9pKdJo/discussion) of this in the question you posted in the mongodb-user group

Answer (score 2):

I think the document scheme you have is going to make it hard for you to query, even if MongoDB supported wildcard matches in this manner (it currently does not).  Basically it would come down to doing a lot of table scans.

Is there a reason for having Age as a property of surname?

An alternative would be to have a document structure more along the lines of

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "Name" : "something",
    "Surname" : "JON",
    "Age" : 10
}
```

Which would be more handy for queries:

```
db.user.find({"Name":"something"})
db.user.find({"Age":{"$gte":5}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..Hi Andre, The above is an example. In our case we have multiple sub documents....like  {'Name':{'Surname':{'JON1':{'AGE':10}},{'JON2':{'AGE':5}}}} .....thought of separating as u suggested but it will complicate the table even more...

Comment: What is "Jon1", "Jon2" etc?  Are these persons surnames?  The way they are modelled now is as keynames, but they look like data.  If they are actually data, you'd be better off doing something like {"Name":{"Surname":{"SNameText":"Jon1", "Age":10}}} which would let you do db.find({"Name.Surname.Age":{"$gte":10}})

Comment: Andre is right. You are confusing key-names with data(the values). The only job of a key-name is to give an idea of what value it contains. It itself is not supposed to act like data. Keeping age inside surname key doesn't make sense.